# VM is running on image that has been scheduled for deprecation

Tags: azure, image, virtual-machine

Monthes ago my colleague created few Virtual Machines in Microsoft Azure. During the creation process it was taken the Windows 10 image that is published by Microsoft.
Recently I the information, that this image habe been scheduled for deprication.
It's refereing me to this Microsoft artictle ([LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/deprecated-images)).

What I'm looking for is to update this image without having to reinstall the VM.
I'm looking for a solution since few days, but didn't find any heplful information, beside of this ([LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/deprecated-images#how-do-i-migrate-my-workloads-to-another-image)).

> If you want to keep using an image that is scheduled for deprecation,
> generalize the VM, deallocate the VM, then create a custom image for
> your VM or scale set. Then change the VM or scale set deployment to
> point to the custom image. For more information, see [Capture an image
> of a VM in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/capture-image-portal).

So that's why my questions are:

- Is it possible to upgrade the image plan of my current VM without reinstall it?
- Is it correct that I have to deallocate the VM, generalize the VM, create new VM without any plan info and than delete old VM? Or is there any easier way to do it, like a powershell command for example?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Keep VM instance OS updated?

Comment: @jikuja I want to make sure that 1) this check doesn't happen 2) make my VM up-to-date always to latest version. Important: I don't want to reinstall the VM, because on these VM's are a lot of different apps installed, it would be much effort for less benefit in our case.

Comment: "this check doesn't happen"? What do you mean?

Comment: @jikuja I mean with "this check doesn't happen" that Microsoft shouldn't check anymore in future for Image / Version. I'm expecting from MS Azure that it provides me a VM Service, without caring about which OS version is running on this VM. Of course we try always to be up-to-date with the OS, but this should be our business.

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers really limited support for in-place OS updates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows-in-place-upgrade. => No-go in this case

---

The most important set of information from the deprecation email/documentation:

> Active VM instances won't be impacted.
>
> New VM instances can't be created from any of the impacted images.

Image deprecation has no effect on existing VM instances. Only creation of new instances will be impossible unless you save the image manually from running VM instance.

---

The proper way to keep operating system updated is to use OS' built-in features to install OS updates or let Azure Azure trigger update installations:

- Windows update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-windows-3c5ae7fc-9fb6-9af1-1984-b5e0412c556a#WindowsVersion=Windows_10
- Older Azure Update management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Ftoc.json
- Newer still on preview, Update Management Center(UMC): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/update-center/

I recommend checking UMC if that has update management features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Created sample virtual machine on windows 10 image published by Microsoft like below:

[image]

Yes, you are right. You need to deallocate the VM, generalize it, create a new VM using a custom image, and then delete the old VM. This process ensures that your VM is using an updated image while preserving your existing VM's configuration.

Connect with remote desktop on your vm -> In RDP -> `windows+R` -> type sysprep

[image]

Now, on virtual machine click on **`Capture`**  -> create an image like below:

[image]

Now you can create a custom VM image as per your requirement like below:

[image]

Once the image is created, click on create VM like below:

[image]

*Note* : Custom VM deployment takes time once deployed. It deallocates the old VM generalize the VM and create new VM with custom images like below:

[image]

***References:***

[Create a VM from a generalized image in a gallery - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-generalized-image-version?tabs=portal%2Ccli2%2Cportal3%2Cportal4)

[Create a legacy managed image in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/capture-image-resource)

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. I will follow these steps, but before I have some questions.
1. Does this VM has the same SID after recreating it with a custom image?
2. Is the order right: 1. Sysprep 2. Shutdown and deallocated 3. capture and continue with the instruction from the answer.
3. All apps and data will be copied also after this capture right?
4. So I have to do this steps for each VM with publisher from Microsoft, right?

Comment: SID is a unique identifier associated with each Windows system, when you create a new VM from an image, it effectively creates a new instance with a new SID. SID will be differed and you can follow the same steps app and data will be copied except temporary storage file You can click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons, if this helps you. Refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/SO31buq.png)